# Python: How to access the dictionary that has specific key-values in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[
{"START":"Denver", "END":"Chicago", "Num":0},
{"START":"Dallas", "END":"Houston", "Num":3},
{"START":"Virginia", "END":"Boston", "Num":1},
{"START":"Washington", "END":"Maine", "Num":7}
]
```

How do I access the dictionary in this list that has `"START":"Virginia", "END":"Boston"` in most pythonic way?

Comment: Do you guarantee uniqueness? Can the ordering change?

Comment: Yes I guarantee uniqueness, and ordering can't change.

Comment: i'm trying to change "Num" values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most Pythonic way is probably a list comprehension:

```
[ d for d in dict_list if d["START"] == "Virginia" and d["END"] == "Boston" ]
```

As mgilson pointed out, if you are assuming that there's only one item in the list with that pair of locations, you can use `next` with the same generator expression, instead of the brackets.  That will return just the matching dict, rather than a one-item list containing it:

```
trip = next( d for d in dict_list 
               if d["START"] == "Virginia" and d["END"] == "Boston" )
```

Either way, the result references the same dict object(s) as the original list, so you can make changes:

```
trip["Num"] = trip["Num"] + 1
```

And those changes will be there when accessed through the original list:

```
print(dict_list[2]["Num"])    # 2
```

As Ashwini Chaudhary indicated in his answer, your search may itself be specified as a dict.  In that case, the `if` condition in the generator expression is a little different, but the logic is otherwise the same:

```
search = { "START": "Virginia", "END": "Boston" }
trip = next(d for d in dict_list if all(i in d.items() for i in search.items()))
```

Comment: The latter can also be written as `...if set(d.items()) & set(search.items())`

Comment: after accessing this dict, i will change the value of its "Num" key, how to do it?

Comment: You could also do `next( d for d in lis if d['START'] == 'Virginia' ...)`

Answer (score 2):

use `all()` with `dict.items()`:

```
In [66]: lis=[                                      
   ....: {"START":"Denver", "END":"Chicago", "Num":0},
   ....: {"START":"Dallas", "END":"Houston", "Num":3},
   ....: {"START":"Virginia", "END":"Boston", "Num":1},
   ....: {"START":"Washington", "END":"Maine", "Num":7}
   ....: ]

In [67]: for x in lis:                              
   ....:         if all(y in x.items() for y in search.items()):
   ....:                 x['Num']="foobar"        #change Num here
   ....:         

In [68]: lis
Out[68]: 
[{'END': 'Chicago', 'Num': 0, 'START': 'Denver'},
 {'END': 'Houston', 'Num': 3, 'START': 'Dallas'},
 {'END': 'Boston', 'Num': 'foobar', 'START': 'Virginia'},
 {'END': 'Maine', 'Num': 7, 'START': 'Washington'}]
```

using a `list comprehension`:

```
In [58]: [x for x in lis if all(y in x.items() for y in search.items())]
Out[58]: [{'END': 'Boston', 'Num': 1, 'START': 'Virginia'}]
```

Comment: Or in comprehension form, `[x for x in lis if all(y in x.items() for y in search.items())]`

Comment: after accessing this dict, i will change the value of its "Num" key, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to do the search a lot of times and you know there is one and only one dict for every pair of locations you could create a dict from the list like this:

```
d = dict(((x['START'], x['END']), x) for x in list_of_dicts)
```

And then just do lookups in the new dict like this:

```
found_dict = d[('Virginia', 'Chicago')]
```

You could change `found_dict` then however you need.

Comment: or: `{','.join([x['START'], x['END']]): x for x in list_of_dicts}`

Comment: @Eric, sure for Python >= 2.7

Comment: why join them?  better to use a `(start, end)` tuple as the key

Answer (score 1):

If each item is unique, then you could do this:

```
def get_dict(items, start, end):
    for dict in items:
        if dict['START'] == start and dict['END'] == end:
            return dict
```

And then:

```
>>> items = [
    {"START":"Denver", "END":"Chicago", "Num":0},
    {"START":"Dallas", "END":"Houston", "Num":3},
    {"START":"Virginia", "END":"Boston", "Num":1},
    {"START":"Washington", "END":"Maine", "Num":7}
]
>>> get_dict(items, 'Virginia', 'Boston')
{"START":"Virginia", "END":"Boston", "Num":1}
```

It's fairly straightforward, but I thought I'd post it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: `return None` is completely redundant, since a function returns none by default.